# fileobserver in android

Tags: android, file

I want to observe `/sdcard/` that if file or folder copy in `/sdcard/` or sub folders of `/sdcard/` i will be notified.

I try [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html)  but the problem is `FileObserver` just detect copy procedure that will happen in `/sdcard/` and it does not notify copy procedure that happen in sub folders.
should i make a `FileObserver` for all of folder?It is bad performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you will have to make `FileObserver` objects for every folder in the SD card. And with it come issues such as knowing which folder's `onEvent()` is called and updating internal Strings when folders are renamed.

There is already an issue filed about it in [Issue 12479](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12479). There is also a patch available written by the same guy who opened the issue. I haven't tried that patch though so can't comment on it.

Comment: recursive function is a bad solution.because of stack and many things.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced similar situation. The [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) Doc in google do say that it can notify changes in all subfolders once you set the Listener for the parent folder, but it wont work in that way. Some of the StackOverflowers suggest to go with the opensource FileObserver, so did I and its perfectly working. Here is the code..

```
public class RecursiveFileObserver extends FileObserver
{

    public static final int CHANGES_ONLY = CREATE | DELETE | CLOSE_WRITE | MOVE_SELF | MOVED_FROM | MOVED_TO;

    List<SingleFileObserver> mObservers;
    String mPath;
    int mMask;
    public String directoryPath;

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path) {
        this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
        directoryPath = path;
    }

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
        super(path, mask);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = mask;
    }

    @Override
    public void startWatching() {
        if (mObservers != null) return;

        mObservers = new ArrayList<SingleFileObserver>();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(mPath);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            String parent = stack.pop();
            mObservers.add(new SingleFileObserver(parent, mMask));
            File path = new File(parent);
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (null == files) continue;
            for (File f : files)
            {
                if (f.isDirectory() && !f.getName().equals(".") && !f.getName().equals("..")) {
                    stack.push(f.getPath());
                }
            }
        }

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.startWatching();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopWatching() {
        if (mObservers == null) return;

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.stopWatching();
        }
        mObservers.clear();
        mObservers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String filePath) 
    {
        event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;


        synchronized (this)
        {
            //Log.i("FileManager", "event occured:"+filePath);

            if (event == FileObserver.CREATE || event == FileObserver.MOVED_TO) 
            {

                return;
            }

            if (event == FileObserver.DELETE  || event == FileObserver.MOVED_FROM) 
            {

                return;
            }
        }
    }


    class SingleFileObserver extends FileObserver 
    {
        String mPath;

        public SingleFileObserver(String path) {
            this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
            mPath = path;
        }

        public SingleFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
            super(path, mask);
            mPath = path;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            String newPath = mPath + "/" + path;
            RecursiveFileObserver.this.onEvent(event, newPath);
        }
    }
}
```